# Ramda error with compose and reduce > Cannot read property '@@transducer/step' of undefined

Tags: ramda.js

I have a strange error (for me) with Ramda:

When I use in a composition:

```
const total_ok = R.compose(
  values => R.reduce(sum_value, 0)(values),
  R.prop('items')
)
```

all work fine.

But if I refactor it like that:

```
const total_bad = R.compose(
  R.reduce(sum_value, 0),
  R.prop('items')
)
```

I have the error "Cannot read property '@@transducer/step' of undefined".

I don't understand why.

You can test the code here: http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=const%20total_ok%20%3D%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20values%20%3D%3E%20R.reduce%28sum_value%2C%200%29%28values%29%2C%0A%20%20R.prop%28%27items%27%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20total_bad%20%3D%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20R.reduce%28sum_value%2C%200%29%2C%0A%20%20R.prop%28%27items%27%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20sum_value%20%3D%20%28duration%2C%20item%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20duration%20%2B%20item.value%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Alet%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20items%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%202%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%203%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%22total%28data%29%3A%20%22%2Btotal_ok%28data%29%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%22total%28data%29%3A%20%22%2Btotal_bad%28data%29%29%3B

Have you an idea?

Frédéric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply because you're trying to use `sum_value` before you define it.  When you introduce the lambda expression, `values => R.reduce(sum_value, 0)(values)`, you delay the evaluation of `sum_values` until after you've defined it, and everything works.

If you were to move the definition of `sum_value` above `total_bad` (or similarly if it were a function declaration or a `var` statement, and therefore hoisted) then this would just work.

You can see an updated version in **[the REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=const%20sum_value%20%3D%20%28duration%2C%20item%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20duration%20%2B%20item.value%3B%0A%7D%3B%20%0A%0Aconst%20total_ok%20%3D%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20values%20%3D%3E%20R.reduce%28sum_value%2C%200%29%28values%29%2C%0A%20%20R.prop%28%27items%27%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20total_bad%20%3D%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20R.reduce%28sum_value%2C%200%29%2C%0A%20%20R.prop%28%27items%27%29%0A%29%0A%0A%0Alet%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20items%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%202%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%203%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%22total%28data%29%3A%20%22%2Btotal_ok%28data%29%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%22total%28data%29%3A%20%22%2Btotal_bad%28data%29%29%3B)**.